# Minimizing the second moment of the difference of two dependent Poisson variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I want to solve this minimization problem
 $$\underset{\tilde{a}_j}{\operatorname{min}}E \mid \mid \mathcal{P}_{j}(a_{j}) -  \tilde{\mathcal{P}}_{j}(\tilde{a}_{j}) \mid \mid^{2},$$ 
where $\mathcal{P}_{j}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}_{j}$ are dependent Poisson random variables. If they are independent, it is easy to prove that it is solved by taking $\tilde{a}_j= -\frac{1}{2}+a_j$ but I did not find any clue how to solve it when they are dependent because of the covariance. Could anyone give a hint please!!

Comment: You mean they both have a marginal Poisson distribution but are dependent in some way? You need so specify the exact form of dependence as this would dictate the $\bar{a}_j$ you can choose.

Comment: No I mean each one is a Poisson process. The setting of the problem is that I want to build a Poisson process $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ that is very correlated to $\mathcal{P}$ then I want to determine a formula of $\tilde{a}_j$ so this  correlation is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal{P}(t)$ is a Poisson process then for example $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(t):=\mathcal{P}(at)$ where $a>0$ is a Poisson process that is correlated to the original with a paramter $a$. But that is just one option, you need to be more specific about the form of dependence the two processes have.